# Express Returns Cookie , But Not Saved In Browser

Tags: node.js, express, axios, frontend, backend

I am sending my login request from frontend to backend, the backend server just return the cookie and it is visible in the ssl/lock area , but not saved in applications tab

[this is the ssl section where i can receive the cookie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liCS2.png)

[this is the applications tab where it was supposed to save the cookie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0xMw.png)

[The response headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0b8j.png)

im using axios to send request, withCrredentials set to true

```
    const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:8080",
  withCredentials: true,
  headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/json",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://localhost:3000",
  },
});
export const loginManager = async (values) => {
  try {
    const response = await api.post("auth/login", values, {
      withCredentials: true,
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://localhost:3000",
      },
    });

    return response?.data;
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.response) {
      // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
      // that falls out of the range of 2xx
      return error.response.data;
    } else if (error.request) {
      // The request was made but no response was received
      // `error.request` is an instance of XMLHttpRequest in the browser
      // and an instance of http.ClientRequest in node.js

      return error.request;
    } else {
      // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error

      return error.message;
    }
  }
};
```

here is the backend middleware code

```
import AppError from "./utils/appError.js";
const origin = "https://admin-dashboard-umarahmed.pages.dev";

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(
  cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin,
  })
);
app.use(ExpressMongoSanitize());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(morgan("tiny"));
app.disable("x-powered-by");
```

Comment: it's hard to figure out what's going on without any code example. Could you please add how do you send request from Frontend to Backend, please.

Comment: have just updated the post , kindly have a look

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-*` are response headers that come from the server. They do not belong in your request and in general will more than likely result in errors like _"Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers"_.

Comment: so i dont need to set the header manually? in that case it gives me a error of no header present

Comment: Sounds like you haven't configured CORS correctly on the server

Comment: have just updated the code, kindly have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This an example how I use it. This is part of my code.

```
...

const options: cors.CorsOptions = {
        allowedHeaders: [
            'Origin',
            'X-Requested-With',
            'Content-Type',
            'Accept',
            'X-Access-Token',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'
        ],
        credentials: true,
        methods: 'GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
        origin: true,
        preflightContinue: false,
    };

    app.use(cors(options));

    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: true
    }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(cookieParser());

...
```

Use the same sequence